# Witchcraft and their basis

Tags: yoga, tantra, chinnamasta

I've read that the witchcraft tales that we often hear about is dakini siddhi....could some of u kindly elaborate. Here in nepal we hear that witches(dakinis) gather at astamatrika pithas(especially kaumari pithas and chinnamasta pitha of Patan) to perform their midnight worship on amavasya and that they light their own fingers like torches/candles and gather at the matrika shrines for siddhi and worship...do any of u happen to something of the phenomena and tye scriptural sources of witchcraft (had heard from senior yogis that its none other that Bhutadamara Tantra)....and was also curious about their burning fingers used as lamps which is said to radiate blue flame. Any response is highly regarded. Thank u

Comment: This is so cool :D Radiate blue flame and siddhi worship. This is awesome. Is there any other folklore from Nepal about this that you remember ? I’m embarking on a devi-bhakti path and I’m really like the yogini/dakini stories with Devi.

Comment: There are a lot of stories as such...my mom herself encountered one of such Dakini who was naked and radiating blue flame from her finger and doing her worship....they're generally said to congregate in the asta matrika pithas or under a peepal tree during amavasya and perform required dakini worship.....but not much is known about their practice or parampara.

Comment: Thx for replying, what your mom saw, that’s so cool ! I really love this kind of stuff, I’m so drawn to it. I hope someone replies to this question eventually with some proper info for you :D

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!